# Blender doesn's use the graphic card to render and only use the CPU

Tags: rendering, gpu

When I hit render, doesn't matter what settings I change, blender only render the scene with my CPU ignoring my GPU(Nvidia 1060 with 3 GB of RAM). I've tried in **edit** ---> **preferences**---> **system** ---> **cycles rendering** and tried both CUDA and OPTIX.

When I check only the CPU, Blender only the CPU to render(as it should be).

when I check both, Blender only use the CPU(100% usage during the whole render time) ignoring the GPU(it stays at 5-6% with some peak at 15%)

When I check only the GPU, the usage of the CPU stay low but the GPU stay as well at ground level(again no more than 10% with peaks at 19-20% usage).

I tried changing drivers, but nothing changed.
The situation is the same with CUDA and Optix. **How can I force Blender into using the GPU?**

edit: Forgot to mention that I have this issue both on 2.8 and 2.9(I'm currently using 2.93)

Comment: If you checked only GPU and things didn’t gray out or say “no computer device found“, it probably worked. It’s impossible for it not to use the CPU or the GPU. The GPU is probably still at low usage when it renders on it simply because the cycles code is old enough to be somewhat inefficient, and it’s about to be reworked. The GPU is not getting used as often as it could be.

Comment: Tell us how you're checking GPU usage.  Blender's GPU usage doesn't show up in all settings of typical HW monitors.  Doesn't mean it's not being used.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I hoped for a better answer :(. Thank you

Comment: @NathanI I checked with ctrl+alt+canc in windows

Comment: @Wog4lf Was it uninformative?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard not at all, I'm just sad because my CPU is very slow and I really wanted to be able to render with my graphic card. It is a problem of Blender, your answer was perfect(thank you again), it just isn't what I wanted to hear.